# Можно ли использовать синхронные модули в асинхронных приложениях Python

Tags: python, discord.py, асинхронность, async-await

```
if command == None:
        # Если после команды /play ничего не ввели
        await ctx.send(embed = ms.playErrorEmbed(mention))
        return
```

Использую discord.py, который является асинхронным, для написания бота. Для меня всё эта тема оптимизации очень новая, поэтому пока разбираюсь в этом только на совсем начальном уровне. И вот возник вопрос.

В коде выше ms - объект класса mesg, я импортировал собственный модуль со всеми сообщениями бота, чтобы не хранить их в main.py. Логика следующая - если после команды /play ничего не ввели (это неправильно), то выводим пользователю сообщение об этом с помощью объекта embed. Именно такой объект и формирует мой модуль:

````
# Файл для хранения всех сообщений бота
class mesg:
    def playErrorEmbed(ctx, mention):
        # Возвращает текст (embed) о том, что мы не передали url
        textinside = f"{mention}\n" + """```Для использования команды введите:

/play <url>```"""

        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
        embed.add_field(name="Произошла ошибка!\n", value=textinside)
        return embed
````

И я честно не понимаю, правильно ли так делать или это вообще ужасная ошибка, за которую я должен гореть в аду. То есть нужно ли мне сделать эту функцию асинхронной или можно оставить так, пока работает. Как сделать правильно? Буду очень благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: "Можно ли использовать синхронные модули в асинхронных приложениях" - короткий ответ - да. Более длинный ответ - если нет каких-то длительных блокирующих поток операций, то без проблем. Если что-то длительное, то возможно придется переделывать логику, чтобы работало асинхронно, ну или самый простой вариант - запускать через `await asyncio.to_thread()`